# Deletion stubs not being purged - IBM Domino

Tags: ibm-domino

Running Domino 8.5.3 and have found one of my databases has never purged any deletion stubs.  I have checked the following:

- Updall is set to run in ini file at 2am.
- No errors when Updall runs.
- Remove documents not modified not modified in last days is set to 90.  I have changed this number of days and re run updall.  No purging.
- I have checked the stubs using ScanEzi - they date back to 2005.
- I have run a fixup, compact and updall.
- Using ScanEZ I can see that the purge interval is set correctly, and that they documents should have deleted -2000 days ago (lol).
- The issue appears to be server wide.  Not just the main application, but also names.nsf and other custom apps.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you check all available date- time- values in your database? Created, Replication History, Activity- Log, ACL- Log, Created / Modified in your documents, Cutoff- date for replication? This sounds like a "time- creep": It might be, that your servers' date was set to a date in the future (even if it was for one minute)... This can cause such strange behaviour...

Comment: Hi @TorstenLink - I have checked these, no future dates (have also checked admin4).  what I find so strange is that it is across the whole server.  I will test the other servers in the domain on the weekend to see if they are clearing out from there. I have confirmed that they are not deleting from this server, rather than deleting and replicating back in.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea what I saw on a Server some time ago. The replication cut of date (under Replication Settings) wasn´t correct and additional to that another server do not have the proper rights in order to replicate.

So here is how I fixed that:

- Removed any replica on all servers, so that I have only one (I copied the old one just in case locally to a non domino folder)
- Then I fixed the ACL and make sure its ok
- Then I fixed all the other settings like the cut off date and and and

Once I´m happy with the result I created new replicas on the other servers.